# bootstrap will not print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added bootstrap last minute, before I added it, page printed correctly. Now, it does not. Ive looked at the other answers to this question, but none seemed to directly apply to me.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2><span>Palette</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">      
        <div class="pri-circle circle" data-palette-name="primary" id="color1"></div>
        <div>
            <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="#" data-picker-for="#color1" class="theme" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">      
        <div class="pd-circle circle" data-palette-name="primary-dark" id="color2"></div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="#" data-picker-for="#color2" class="theme"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it won't print? It works fine for me from here: http://www.bootply.com/21oJervPdN

Comment: If you mean that it's not printing the way you want it to after adding Bootstrap, then the issue is most likely a conflict between its CSS and yours, in which case you'll need to tell us in detail what the issues are and show us the code causing the problem.

Comment: Here is a fiddle! I know how much yall hate people who are dumb, so I will preface you looking at my code by saying that YES I am still learning. And sometimes I get stumped... Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it. https://jsfiddle.net/S_Words/abt6gg45/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you added it last minute I suspect you added your `bootstrap.css` file last minute as well. If you have custom CSS that overrides bootstrap default you need to make sure your costum CSS file parses after `bootstrap.css`, so make sure your file order in your header is correct.